# Installed SASS from Terminal + Ruby on Rails. Styles not working. Ubuntu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, sass

I've done everything said [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) and [here](http://sass-lang.com/install).

I've changed the file extension to `.sass`, but my browser doesn't load the styles. Did I miss something?

Comment: I've got a doubt... Did you *simply* renamed your `whatever.css` into `whatever.sass` ?

Comment: Did you miss something? I'm sorry but my mind reading trojan is out of date. If you are looking for sensible and/or useful answers/comments please give more details. What did you do?

Comment: You do understand that the purpose of Sass is to compile it to CSS, right?  Because there are no browsers that understand Sass.

Comment: @zessx I did rename into `.sass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass is a CSS pre-processor, and it seems you're using it without understanding it. Web browsers can't understand SASS code, and they won't. You need to "ask" Sass to generate the CSS browsers will use.

When Ruby and Sass are are installed, you need to:

- Have a `.sass` file with your SASS code
- Run the command `sass input.sass:output.css` (with some options if you want) to **compile** the SASS code and get a generated CSS code
- Link your generated CSS file in your HTML

Comment: Do I need to run the command in the Terminal, or is it something I put at the beginning/end of the .sass file?

Comment: You need to run the command yourself. You can also use an external soft (as Compass, Scout...) to watch your Sass files, detect changes and run the command automatically. Another solution is to run the command each time you save your file (this method highly depends of you editor).

Comment: I am using Brackets as my editor. I think it has some kind of extension for that kind of stuff.